# how to replace the examples content in this yaml file using python?

Tags: python, yaml

```yaml
- intent: magic

  examples: |
    - magic
    - Magick
    - jadu
    - magickkk
```

I want to replace "magic" with other any words. How can i do it? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Open the file. Read it line by line. Use *replace()* to substitute 'magic' with something else. Rewrite the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some yml libraries that can help you like [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) or [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/).
I always used pyyaml but i found it a little bit triky to produce format you want. I managed to produce your format in output more easier with ruamel.yaml. However i think these library works in a similar way, you can use what you want.
I tried this

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open('file.yml') as file:
    data = yaml.load(file)
    print(data)
    data[0]['intent'] = "greetings"
    with open('file.yml', 'w') as out:
        yaml.dump(data, out)
```

The output will be

```
- intent: greetings
    examples: |
      - magic
      - Magick
      - jadu
      - magickkk
```

I don't understand why, but sometimes the output format is

```
- intent: greetings
    examples: |-
      - magic
      - Magick
      - jadu
      - magickkk
```

But i don't think that the "-" is a problem. In fact yml file is readed correctly.

Am i wrong or this is rasa nlu.yml file ? :)